# R - How to both unlist and concatenate

Tags: r, list, data-structures

Using `lapply`, I've fed a vector of inputs into a function that for each input returns a list of two vectors - possible nth-grams and their probabilities. I end up with a list of lists (lol) with this structure:

```
> str(lol)
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ np1  : chr [1:7] "a" "years" "the" "my" ...
  ..$ probs: num [1:7] 0.1481 0.1357 0.0841 0.0698 0.0522 ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ np1  : chr [1:167] "the" "a" "my" "years" ...
  ..$ probs: num [1:167] 0.2745 0.0924 0.0605 0.0437 0.0334 ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ np1  : chr [1:9493] "the" "a" "my" "this" ...
  ..$ probs: num [1:9493] 0.267 0.0777 0.0239 0.0169 0.0158 ...
```

But what I'm aiming for is a single list in which all vectors `$np1` are concatenated and all `$probs` vectors are as well. I tried using `unlist(..., recursive = F)` to get the list of two vectors, and it's gotten me closer to what I'm looking for than using `unlist` without the recursive flag.

```
> str(unlist(lapply(inputs.list, function(x){...}), recursive = F))
List of 6
 $ np1  : chr [1:7] "a" "years" "the" "my" ...
 $ probs: num [1:7] 0.1481 0.1357 0.0841 0.0698 0.0522 ...
 $ np1  : chr [1:167] "the" "a" "my" "years" ...
 $ probs: num [1:167] 0.2745 0.0924 0.0605 0.0437 0.0334 ...
 $ np1  : chr [1:9493] "the" "a" "my" "this" ...
 $ probs: num [1:9493] 0.267 0.0777 0.0239 0.0169 0.0158 ...
```

But not quite there...

Is there a method that would help me futher consolidate the flatten list into a list of only two vectors as described?

Here a reproducible example to work with:

```
example1 <- list("time in"=list(np1=c("the", "a", "my", "years"), probs=c(0.2745, 0.0924, 0.0605, 0.0437)),"in"=list(np1=c("the", "a", "my", "this"), probs=c(0.267, 0.0777, 0.0239, 0.0169)))
> str(example1)
List of 2
 $ time in:List of 2
  ..$ np1  : chr [1:4] "the" "a" "my" "years"
  ..$ probs: num [1:4] 0.2745 0.0924 0.0605 0.0437
 $ in     :List of 2
  ..$ np1  : chr [1:4] "the" "a" "my" "this"
  ..$ probs: num [1:4] 0.267 0.0777 0.0239 0.0169
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an "unlist" solution that is similar to what you were working on. It relies on the vectors you are interested in always alternating (e.g., it is always `nth` and then `probs`. Good luck and let me know if it doesn't work for you!

```
unlist_ed <- unlist(example1, recursive = F)

list(
  np1 = unlist(unlist_ed[c(T, F)]),
  probs = unlist(unlist_ed[c(F, T)])
)

$np1
time in.np11 time in.np12 time in.np13 time in.np14      in.np11      in.np12      in.np13      in.np14 
       "the"          "a"         "my"      "years"        "the"          "a"         "my"       "this" 

$probs
time in.probs1 time in.probs2 time in.probs3 time in.probs4      in.probs1      in.probs2      in.probs3 
        0.2745         0.0924         0.0605         0.0437         0.2670         0.0777         0.0239 
     in.probs4 
        0.0169
```

EDIT: I thought of another solution that relies on the vector names being the same, but it is much faster (not that that is the goal). Wanted to update!

```
dplyr::bind_rows(example1)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  np1    probs
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 the   0.274 
2 a     0.0924
3 my    0.0605
4 years 0.0437
5 the   0.267 
6 a     0.0777
7 my    0.0239
8 this  0.0169
```

Not a perfect benchmark:

```
example1 <- rapply(example1, function(x) rep(x, 1e4), how = "list")
example1 <- rep(example1, 100)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(

o1 = {
    Reduce(function(...) Map(c, ...), example1)
  },
  o2 = {
    unlist_ed <- unlist(example1, recursive = F)

    list(
      nth = unlist(unlist_ed[c(T, F)]),
      probs = unlist(unlist_ed[c(F, T)])
    )
  },
  o3 = {
    transpose(example1) %>% map(flatten) %>% map(unlist)
  },
  o4 = {
    binded <- dplyr::bind_rows(example1)

    list(binded$np1,
         binded$probs)
  },
  times = 1

)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
   o1 5022.25495 5022.25495 5022.25495 5022.25495 5022.25495 5022.25495     1
   o2 5146.75265 5146.75265 5146.75265 5146.75265 5146.75265 5146.75265     1
   o3 2491.21422 2491.21422 2491.21422 2491.21422 2491.21422 2491.21422     1
   o4   83.32919   83.32919   83.32919   83.32919   83.32919   83.32919     1
```

Comment: Nice job of leveraging the alternating vectors. This would be one solution.

Comment: Speed is an issue, actually. It's part of a shiny app, and the nth-grams and their probabilities are output from a user input dependent reactive function.

Answer (score 4):

Two lists can be combined in your desired way with `Map`, as in

```
Map(c, example1[[1]], example1[[2]])
# $np1
# [1] "the"   "a"     "my"    "years" "the"   "a"     "my"    "this" 
#
# $probs
# [1] 0.2745 0.0924 0.0605 0.0437 0.2670 0.0777 0.0239 0.0169
```

So, as to merge the whole list of lists we may do

```
Reduce(function(...) Map(c, ...), example1[c(1, 1, 2)])
# $np1
#  [1] "the"   "a"     "my"    "years" "the"   "a"     "my"    "years" "the"   "a"     "my"    "this" 
#
# $probs
#  [1] 0.2745 0.0924 0.0605 0.0437 0.2745 0.0924 0.0605 0.0437 0.2670 0.0777 0.0239 0.0169
```

where I purposefully made the input of length 3 as to demonstrate the functionality. In your case we need

```
Reduce(function(...) Map(c, ...), lol)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/):

```
library(tidyverse)

transpose(example1) %>% map(flatten) %>% map(unlist)
```

Output:

```
$np1
[1] "the"   "a"     "my"    "years" "the"   "a"     "my"    "this" 

$probs
[1] 0.2745 0.0924 0.0605 0.0437 0.2670 0.0777 0.0239 0.0169
```